# Sending custom HTTP headers with Ruby

Tags: ruby, http, sinatra

I want to send custom headers along with an HTTP request.
I created the following based on the example at [ruby-doc, Net::HTTP, Setting Headers](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Setting+Headers) but my version fails with "Connection reset by peer":

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
require 'fileutils'
require 'net/http'
require 'time'

cached_response = 'index.html'                                       # Added
FileUtils.touch(cached_response) unless File.exist?(cached_response) # Added
uri = URI("https://www.apple.com/#{cached_response}")                # Changed
file = File.stat cached_response

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['If-Modified-Since'] = file.mtime.rfc2822

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) {|http|
  http.request(req)
}

open cached_response, 'w' do |io|
  io.write res.body
end if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

However, sending without the custom header works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
require 'fileutils'
require 'net/http'
require 'time'

cached_response = 'index.html'
uri = URI("https://www.apple.com/#{cached_response}")
FileUtils.touch(cached_response) unless File.exist?(cached_response)
file = File.stat cached_response

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)                                        # Ignored
req['If-Modified-Since'] = file.mtime.rfc2822                        # Ignored

res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)                                    # Changed

open cached_response, 'w' do |io|
  io.write res.body
end if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
```

Can someone explain why my implementation of the example Ruby code doesn't work?

I added similar code to a couple Sinatra routes:

```
get '/test1' do
  uri = URI('https://www.apple.com/index.html')
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  req['Accept'] = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT']
  res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) { |h| h.request(req) }
  headers = res.to_hash
  headers.delete('transfer-encoding')
  [res.code.to_i, headers, res.body]
end
```

then

```
get '/test2' do
  uri = URI('https://www.apple.com/index.html')
  res = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  headers = res.to_hash
  headers.delete('transfer-encoding')
  [res.code.to_i, headers, res.body]
end
```

With /test1, I get

```
curl -iv 'http://localhost:9292/test1'
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9292 (#0)
> GET /test1 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9292
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 
< Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 5582
Content-Length: 5582
< Server: WEBrick/1.4.2 (Ruby/2.5.0/2018-12-06)
Server: WEBrick/1.4.2 (Ruby/2.5.0/2018-12-06)
< Date: Sat, 22 Dec 2018 16:51:03 GMT
Date: Sat, 22 Dec 2018 16:51:03 GMT
< Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive

< 
EOFError: end of file reached
    ...
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

With /test2, I get

```
curl -iv 'http://localhost:9292/test2'
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9292 (#0)
> GET /test2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9292
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
...
<etc. HTML written to console>
```

Looks like the request headers are identical. Same four lines.

If I add the Accept header to the curl command, the request Accept header changes as expected for both, and both return the same results as before (/test1: 500; /test2: 200)

```
curl -iv -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:9292/test2'
...
> GET /test2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9292
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Hmm... Turns out that last bit is a red herring. No one is surprised the Accept header is set correctly by curl. It would be helpful to see the (incorrect?) Request headers from the `.request(req)` commands in the `Net::HTTP.start` blocks and compare them to the (correct) request headers from `Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. When setting up an HTTP request, using the 'https' scheme does not automatically enable TLS/SSL. You must do this explicitly before the request starts. Here's my updated version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'fileutils'
require 'net/http'
require 'time'

cached_response = 'index.html'                                     # Added
FileUtils.touch cached_response unless File.exist? cached_response # Added
uri = URI("https://www.apple.com/#{cached_response}")              # Changed
file = File.stat cached_response

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
req['If-Modified-Since'] = file.mtime.rfc2822

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.hostname, uri.port)                       # Added
http.use_ssl = uri.scheme == 'https'                               # Added
res = http.start { |h| h.request(req) }                            # Changed

if res.is_a?(Net::HTTPSuccess)
  File.open cached_response, 'w' do |io|
    io.write res.body
  end
end
```